# Cannot find classification schema reference in JSON Schema

Tags: jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I have a product schema which tries to reference an id in my document.  It is a common reference to multiple objects. Unfortunately, my ide claims classification reference cannot be found.  I am very new to json schemas and find only snippets which don't quite show how the references are supposed to work.  Here is my schema.

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "$id": "https://digital.com/schemas/products",
  "description": "Schema for Product Data",
  "title": "Products",
  "type": "object",
  "required": ["products"],
  "properties": {
    "products": {
      "type": "array"
    },
    "options": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "productId": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "productName": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "categories": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "allOf": [
              { "$ref":"/products/classification" }
            ]
          },
          "productType": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["electronic", "digital", "internet", "video"]
          }
        },
        "required": ["productId"]
      }
    },
    "classification": {
      "$id": "/products/classification",
      "type":"object",
      "properties": {
        "relevance-score": {
          "type":"integer",
          "minimum": 1,
          "maximum": 5
        },
        "group":{
          "enum":["adult","teen","seniors"]
        }
      }
    },
    "definitions": {
      "mp4": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "mediaType": {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": ["video"]
          },
          "playlength": {
            "type": "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "mp3": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "mediaType": {
          "enum": ["audio"]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have defined a classification object to use in the class property of categories object like this
"$id":"/products/classification".
I tried setting it relative to the $id at the top of the document which is "https://digital.com/schemas/products" but I'm sure I haven't set it correctly. I want to use the classification object in the allOf property of the categories object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reference is `"$ref": "/products/classification"`.  Where is this supposed to point?

Odds are the validator you're using is looking for a schema with the `$id` of `"https://digital.com/products/classification"`.  If the validator doesn't know about this schema (or perhaps is searching for that file), it can't get to it.

---

The other possibility is that you intend this to be a JSON Pointer.  If that's the case, it needs to be URI-formatted: `"#/products/classification"`

However, this location doesn't existin within your schema, so it'll need to be updated.

Comment: I set the $id field in classification so that I can use it wherever I use the class property. The classification is             "classification":{
                "$id": "/products/classification", I want to reference it in the class property $ref i.e "class":{
                    "$ref":"/products/classification"
                }

Comment: Just set the `$ref` to the `$id` of the subschema you want to point to. The validator should find it.